# Кодировка и php

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Есть база данных с кодировкой utf8_general_ci
Есть php страница с utf-8 мета тегом.

Но почему-то русский текст в хреновой кодировке, причем не весь, а тот, который берется из БД. Вы можете помочь?

http://likebox.ru/fbtn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл так же должен быть в кодировке utf-8, проверьте её в Notepad++, и при необходимости перекодируйте(без Bom)

Comment: http://gyazo.com/8f0e94d861889e32aef117d4de3a2dfc.png
http://gyazo.com/2cfb3e55256d78117efa26cbf496ed82.png

Comment: Тогда думаю, что дело в базе данных, у вас utf8_unicode_ci, а нужно utf8_general_ci. Ещё как вариант - добавить в начало файла строку : header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); и в файл .htaccess строчку : AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Comment: utf8_general_ci и .htaccess - не дало результатов. Может быть при записи в бд пишется в хрен пойми чем. Как переконвертировать строку в utf-8 перед записью?

Comment: Можно конечно использовать http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php , но дело думаю не в этом. После подключения к базе данных необходимо вручную указывать кодировку соединения mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); у вас есть такое?

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо!

Comment: Слава богу)

Answer (score 0):

А с mySQL надо добавить

> ```
> mysql_query(”SET NAMES ‘utf8′”);
> mysql_query(”SET collation_connection=’utf8_general_ci’”);
> mysql_query(”SET collation_server=’utf8_general_ci’”);
> mysql_query(”SET character_set_client=’utf8′”);
> mysql_query(”SET character_set_connection=’utf8′”);
> mysql_query(”SET character_set_results=’utf8′”);
> mysql_query(”SET character_set_server=’utf8′”);
> ```

Comment: Надобность в последних строках отпадает, т.к. mysql_query(”SET NAMES ‘utf8′”); выполняет все эти операции.